# Assignment Operator (=) overloading in xtend

Tags: xtend

I'm considering the use of **xtend** for a project that would benefit from its operator overloading, as that would greatly enhance readability of the code.

However what I didn't seem to come accross is assignment operator overloading. Did I miss it or doesn't it exist?

I'm not an expert but wouldn't that be technically just as feasible as the solution used for other operators like `+` that is mapped to `e1.operator_plus(e2)`?

Is assignment overloading something that is foreseen (when?) or is there a good reason not to support it (even in the future)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to overload the plain assignment operator `=`. It may be considered in the future, but would require architectural and semantical refinements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I should read that "Not possible" as "Not implemented but technically not impossible", correct? Is that something that is planned? Can we vote for features somewhere? ;-)

Comment: Feel free to create a ticket and describe a convincing use case. From the top of my head it's hard to tell if technically possible or not, but concrete scenarios help to evaluate possible solutions.